# How to reset the pointer of a nested binary tree?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

In General, write a module to work with a binary tree. As values we have the word. The essence of the module, the search of words in the dictionary. And so, the problem: if you repeatedly call the function search with the word which is in the dictionary - it finds everything is OK. After enter few times wrong words, and then again a word from the dictionary. Will be given instead of True -> False.

It seems to me that overwritten the original pointer to the parent, with each recursive iteration _search. And in later branches, just not the desired word.

Question: How to keep the base variable Dictionary? I mean its a pointer. Overwrite variable to another variable does not help. It is written to the same address and all here ;(

Sorry is bad english.

Usage:

```
uses MrBinTree;

var binTree := new _binTree;
binTree.search('test');
```

Module:

```
unit MrBinTree;

interface
  uses General;
type
  PDictionary = ^_Dictionary; { Указатель на узел }
  _Dictionary = record { Тип где будем хранить информацию }
    data: string;
    left, right: PDictionary; { ссылки на дочерние левые и правые элементы }
  end;

  _binTree = class
  private
    Dictionary, {Адрес корня дерева}
    owner: PDictionary; {Владелец результата поиска}
    word: integer; {Искомое слово в символьном исполнении}

    procedure add(var Dictionary: PDictionary; word: string);
    procedure loadDictionary;
    function _search(var Dictionary: PDictionary; word: string) : PDictionary;
    procedure deleteTree(var Tree1: PDictionary );
  public
    constructor Create;
    function search(var word: string) : boolean;
  end;
implementation
  constructor _binTree.Create;
  begin;
    self.loadDictionary;
  end;

  procedure _binTree.deleteTree(var Tree1: PDictionary );
  begin
  if Tree1 <> nil then
    begin
      self.DeleteTree (Tree1^.LEFT);
      self.DeleteTree (Tree1^.RIGHT);
      Dispose(Tree1);
    end;
  end;

  procedure _binTree.loadDictionary;
  var
    i: integer;
    word: string;
  begin
    AssignFile(input, 'dictionary.txt'); {Откроем поток}
    Reset(input); { Откроем файл }
    while not EOF(input) do { Итерируем до того,пока не дойдем до конечной строки }
    begin
     ReadLn(input, word); { Читаем строку }
     self.add(self.Dictionary, word);
    end;
    CloseFile(input); { Закроем поток }
  end;

  {Добавление набора символов в дерево}
  procedure _binTree.add(var Dictionary: PDictionary; word: string);
  begin
    {Для начала проверим наличие корней в дереве, если нету,то создадим}
    if (Dictionary = nil) then
    begin
      New(Dictionary); {Выделим памяти}
      Dictionary^.data := word; {Добавим наши символы}
      Dictionary^.left := nil; {Обнулим указатели}
      Dictionary^.right:= nil; {Обнулим указатели}
      exit; {Готово, процедуру завершим}
    end;

    {Есть корни в дереве, проверим вводимые символы на размерность, если больше - правое, меньше - левое}
    if ( word < Dictionary^.data ) then
      self.add(Dictionary^.left, word) {если коды символов меньше корня,добавим с левое поддерево}
    else
      self.add(Dictionary^.right, word); {если коды символов больше корня,добавим с правое поддерево}
  end;

  { Абстракция для конечного вызова функции поиска }
  function _binTree.search(var word: string) : boolean;
  var
    reserveDictionary: PDictionary; {Резервная переменная ссылающеяся на адрес дерева}
  begin
    reserveDictionary := self._search(self.Dictionary, word);
    if (reserveDictionary <> nil) then
      Result := true
    else
      Result := false;
  end;

  { Функция поиска по бинарному дереву }
  function _binTree._search(var Dictionary: PDictionary; word: string) : PDictionary;
  var
    save: PDictionary := nil;
  begin
    {Для начала проверим наличие корней в дереве, если нету,то выведем нил}
    if (Dictionary = nil) then
    begin
      Result := nil; { Выводим нил, так как дерево пустое }
      exit;
    end;

    { Если равенство с корнем дерева }
    if (Dictionary^.data = word) then
    begin
      save := Dictionary; { Запишем его адрес }
    end else begin
      if (Dictionary^.data > word) then { Если введенный элемент меньше корня }
        save := self._search(Dictionary^.left, word) { ищем в левом поддереве }
      else
        save := self._search(Dictionary^.right, word); { ищем в правом поддереве }
    end;

    Result := save;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: anyway your binary tree have a leak, if you enter sequential value (like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc..) then you will have big performance penalty and no index at all. if you want an example of a binary tree implementation you can look here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/ in the unit ALAVLBinaryTree (Self-Balancing Binary Trees)

Answer (score 0):

example of how to implement to search in a binary tree :

```
{***************************************************************************************}
function TALBaseAVLBinaryTree.InternalFindNode(idVal: pointer): TALBaseAVLBinaryTreeNode;
var N1: TALBaseAVLBinaryTreeNode;
    CmpRes: Integer;
begin
  N1 := FHead;
  while Assigned(N1) do begin
    CmpRes := CompareNode(IdVal, N1);
    if CmpRes = 0 then begin
      Result := N1;
      Exit;
    end
    else N1 := N1.ChildNodes[CmpRes > 0];
  end;

  Result := nil;
end;
```